# General Settings in Sonar always shows an error

Tags: sonarqube

Whenever I navigate to the administration sections within SonarQube, be that at project level or for the whole system I get the following error banner.

[image]

It also appears once I change the settings on these pages they are not saved and updated?

I cannot see any exceptions thrown in the error logs, so don't know where to go from here. Does anyone from the Sonar team have an idea?

**Update 1**

I have checked the database, and the settings do appear to be updated, but they do not show in the UI.

**Update 2**

Looking at web console I am getting a 404 error from the server.

`https://<my address>/api/settings/values?keys=sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria%2Csonar.cs.ignoreHeaderComments%2Csonar.global.test.exclusions%<Lots and lots of sonar keys>`

This follows what a previous answer (now deleted for some reason) suggests that using `https` and a reverse proxy may be a factor in this Issue

**Update 2.1**

The result of putting the url above returns a generic IIS 404 in a browser

[image]

Comment: Anything interesting in the server log?

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam No everything looks ok. The answer below sounds like a similar issue.

Comment: What version of SonarQube are you on?

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam I am using SonarQube Version 6.2

Comment: You you please display the web Console (for instance on Firefox : Tools -> Web Developer -> Web Console), they reload the page and give us the error that should appear.

Comment: @JulienL.-SonarSourceTeam I have updated the question, I was getting a 404 from the server but am still not sure why the api is getting a 404 when it is used during my build step fine

Comment: What is the result of https://<my address>/api/settings/values ?

Comment: @JulienL.-SonarSourceTeam The result is `{"errors":[{"msg":"The 'keys' parameter is missing"}]}`

Comment: Oups, indeed, you could use instead the full URL https://<my address>/api/settings/values?keys=sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria..... ?

Comment: @JulienL.-SonarSourceTeam Entering the url as requested just returns a generic 404. I have added an image to show the response

Comment: It seems that you are using a reverse proxy or something like that which prevent the WS query to be correctly executed. Have a look at this link https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalmrangers/2016/06/04/running-sonarqube-behind-an-iis-reversed-proxy/, it should help you.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is most probably coming from your reverse proxy. Another user has encountered a similar [issue](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sonarqube/sV6Ac6Z-Y-M/YE1oeQnXDAAJ) and has posted a blog [post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalmrangers/2016/06/04/running-sonarqube-behind-an-iis-reversed-proxy/) to explain how to fix it.